# Autoingestion: read number of downloads programmatically: more than one account needs doesn't work

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to read the number of downloads from my app. This works fine. I use the Autoingestion by Apple.

With this command I get a report:

`java Autoingestion autoingestion0.properties 123456 Sales Daily Summary 20160714`

But now I have an 2nd account and this one is an (Invitation)Account with more than one account. I get an error:

> Your username has access to more than one account. To use this feature please upgrade to Reporter. For more details, see Reporter guide in the Resources and Help section on iTunes Connect.

But I can't find out what Reporter is meaning. I can't find the Reporter guide in the Help section, too. [This](https://www.apple.com/itunesnews/docs/AppStoreReportingInstructions.pdf) is the offical documentation, but there I can't find anything, too...

So maybe somebody has experience with that problem? I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Reporter is Apple's new tool for retrieving iTunes Connect Reports that superseded auto-ingestion. You can read about and also download it here: https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/

If you don't want to install Java, there also seem to be open source alternatives, f.ex. this one written in Python: https://github.com/fedoco/itc-reporter